# Include subtitle display to slideshow

Tags: plugins, wp-query, slideshow

Thanks to Author for this plugin. But There is no option to display subtitle.
There is only 2 options - Title and excerpt. Help me change excerpt to subtitle. I use this function to display subtitles in posts : 
      `<?php if (function_exists('the_subtitle')){ the_subtitle(); }?>`
This is file of fronpage config: I marked the neccesarry lines.

```
<?php
  /*
 Plugin Name: Frontpage-Slideshow
 Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontpage-slideshow/
 Description: Frontpage Slideshow provides a slide show like you can see on <a      href="http://linux.com">linux.com</a> or <a href="http://modulaweb.fr/">modulaweb.fr</a>      front page. <a href="options-general.php?page=frontpage-slideshow">Configuration Page</a>
 Version: 0.9.9.3.8
 Author: Jean-François VIAL
 Author URI: http://www.modulaweb.fr/
 Text Domain: frontpage-slideshow
 */
 /*  Copyright 2009 Jean-François VIAL  (email : jeff@modulaweb.fr)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */
   define ('FRONTPAGE_SLIDESHOW_VERSION', '0.9.9.3.8');
   $fs_already_displayed = false; // the slideshow dont have been displayed yet

 // integrates the template file
 $template = 'default';
 $options = frontpageSlideshow_get_options();
 if (isset($options['values']['fs_template'])) {
if (is_file (dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/'.$options['values']['fs_template'].'          /template.php'))
    $template = $options['values']['fs_template'];
 }
 include (dirname(__FILE__).'/templates/'.$template.'/template.php');


    function frontpageSlideshow($content,$force_display=false,$options=array()) {
global $fs_already_displayed,$fs_last;

if ($fs_already_displayed) return false;

if (!count($options)) $options = frontpageSlideshow_get_options();
if (!$options['values']['fs_is_activated'] && !$force_display) return $content;
$fscategories = implode(',',$options['values']['fs_cats']);

if ((!is_feed() && is_front_page() && $options['values']['fs_insert']!='shortcode') || $force_display) { // the slideshow is only displayed on frontpage
    $fs_already_displayed = true;
    $fsposts = get_posts('category='.$fscategories.'&orderby='.$options['values']['fs_orderby'].'&numberposts='.$options['values']['fs_slides'].'&order='.$options['values']['fs_order']);
    $fsentries = array();
    foreach ($fsposts as $fspost) {
        // format informations
        $title = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-title',true);
        if ($title == '') $title = $fspost->post_title;
        $comment = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-comment',true);
        if ($comment == '' && $options['values']['fs_default_comment_to_excerpt'])
            $comment = $fspost->post_excerpt;
        $buttoncomment = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-button-comment',true);
        $link='';
        // if the option is on, uses the post permalink as slide link
        ($options['values']['fs_default_link_to_page_link'] && get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-link',true) == '') ? $link = get_permalink($fspost->ID) : $link = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-link',true);
        $image = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-picture',true);
        if ($image == '') { // if no image : use the first image on the post
            if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
                if (has_post_thumbnail($fspost->ID)) {
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($fspost->ID),'large');
                    $image = $image[0];
                }
            }
            if ($image=='') {
                if (preg_match('/<img[^>]*src="([^"]*)"/i',$fspost->post_content,$matches)) {
                    $image = $matches[1];
                } else {
                    (is_ssl()) ? $url = str_replace('http://','https://',get_bloginfo('url')) : $url = str_replace('https://','http://',get_bloginfo('url'));
                    $image = $url.'/wp-content/plugins/frontpage-slideshow/images/one_transparent_pixel.gif';
                }
            }
        }

        // handles https for the link
        (!is_ssl()) ? $link = str_replace('https://','http://',$link) : $link = str_replace('http://','https://',$link);
        // handles https for image
        (!is_ssl()) ? $image = str_replace('https://','http://',$image) : $image = str_replace('http://','https://',$image);

        // add a temporal variable to the image url to avoid cache


        // put infos into an array
        $fsentries[] = array('title' => $title.'&nbsp;', 'image' => $image, 'comment' => $comment.'&nbsp;', 'button-comment' => $buttoncomment.'&nbsp;', 'link' => $link, 'post_id' => $fspost->ID);
    }
    // construct the slider
    $fscontent = '';
    $fslast = count($fsentries) -1;
    if (count($fsentries))
        $fscontent = frontpageSlideshow_TPL($fsentries);
    $header = frontpageSlideshow_header(true,$options);
    return "\n<!-- Frontpage Slideshow begin -->\n{$fscontent}\n{$header}\n<!-- Frontpage Slideshow end -->\n{$content}";

} else {
    return $content;
}
  }

 function frontpageSlideshow_init() {
// loads the needed frameworks to load as a safe way
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-effects',WP_PLUGIN_URL .'/frontpage-slideshow/js/jquery-ui-effects.js', array('jquery-ui-core'));
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-effects');
  }
  function frontpageSlideshow_admin_enqueue_scripts() {
// loads the needed frameworks to load as a safe way into admin page
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-droppable');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-selectable');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
  }

  function frontpageSlideshow_header($force_display=false,$options=array()) {
    if (!count($options)) $options = frontpageSlideshow_get_options();
    if (!$options['values']['fs_is_activated'] && !$force_display) return;
    $fscategories = implode(',',$options['values']['fs_cats']);
    $fsposts = get_posts('category='.$fscategories.'&orderby=ID&numberposts='.$options['values']['fs_slides']);
    $fslast = count($fsposts) - 1;

    frontpageSlideshow_JS($options,$fslast);
    frontpageSlideshow_CSS($options,$fslast+1);
    return '
  <script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[
  jQuery(\'head\').append(\'<!--[if IE]><style type="text/css">#fs-text { filter:       alpha(opacity='.str_replace('%','',$options['values']['fs_text_opacity']).'); }</style><![endif]--><style type="text/css">'.str_replace("\n",'       ',str_replace("\t",'',FS_CSS)).'</style>\');
  '.FS_JS.'
  // ]] >
  </script>';
        }

   function frontpageSlideshow_JS_effect($effect,$inout='out') {
$options = frontpageSlideshow_get_options();
if ($effect == 'random') {
    $transitions = array('fade', 'shrink', 'dropout', 'jumpup',     'explode',      'clip', 'dropleft', 'dropright', 'slideleft', 'slideright', 'fold', 'puff');
    $effect = $transitions[rand(0,count($transitions)-1)];
}
$inout = ucfirst(strtolower($inout));
$callback = '';
$duration = $options['values']['fs_transition_on_duration'];
if ($inout == 'Out') {
    $callback = ', fsChangeSlide2';
    $duration = $options['values']['fs_transition_duration'];
}
switch ($effect) {
    case 'scale':
    case 'shrink':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("scale", {}, ' . $duration .      $callback.');';
    case 'dropout':
    case 'drodown':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("drop", {direction: "down"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'jumpup':
    case 'dropup':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("drop", {direction: "up"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'explode':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("explode", {pieces: 32}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'clip':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("clip", {direction: "vertical"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'dropleft':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("drop", {direction: "left"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'dropright':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("drop", {direction: "right"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'slideleft':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'slideright':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("drop", {direction: "right"}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'fold':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("fold", {}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'puff':
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").toggle("puff", {}, ' . $duration . $callback.');';
    case 'fadeout':
    case 'fade':
    default:
        return 'jQuery("#fs-slide").fade'.$inout.'(' . $duration . $callback.');';
}
  }

   function frontpageSlideshow_dedicated_shortcode ($attributes=array(), $content=null)       {
global $fs_already_displayed;

$options = frontpageSlideshow_get_options(); // get default or tweaked options

// dont do anything if
//  - the slideshow has already been displayed
//  - the slideshow has not been activated
//  - the shortcode option is not activated
// parse the other eventually nested shortcodes and display the enventualy specified content
if ($fs_already_displayed || !$options['values']['fs_is_activated'] || $options['values']['fs_insert']!='shortcode') return do_shortcode($content);

$options['values'] = shortcode_atts($options['values'], $attributes);
if (is_array($attributes)) {
    if (array_key_exists('fs_cats',$attributes))
        $options['values']['fs_cats'] = explode(',',$attributes['fs_cats']);
      }
$force_display_if_shortcode = true;
$force_display_if_shortcode = true;
//frontpageSlideshow_header(true,$options);
return frontpageSlideshow('',true,$options);
  }

  class frontpageSlideshow_Widget extends WP_Widget {

function frontpageSlideshow_Widget() {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_text', 'description' =>      __('Arbitrary text or HTML'));
    $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 350);
    $this->WP_Widget('text', __('Text'), $widget_ops, $control_ops);
}

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    extract($args);
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title']);
    $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'] );
    echo $before_widget;
    if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
        <div class="textwidget"><?php echo $instance['filter'] ? wpautop(do_shortcode($text)) : do_shortcode($text); ?></div>
    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
}

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
    if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
        $instance['text'] =  $new_instance['text'];
    else
        $instance['text'] = wp_filter_post_kses( $new_instance['text'] );
    $instance['filter'] = isset($new_instance['filter']);
    return $instance;
}

    function form( $instance ) {
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'text'        => '' ) );
    $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
    $text = format_to_edit($instance['text']);
         ?>
                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php       _e('Title:'); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"        name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php        echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></p>

    <textarea class="widefat" rows="16" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>

    <p><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('filter'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('filter'); ?>" type="checkbox" <?php checked($instance['filter']); ?> />&nbsp;<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('filter'); ?>"><?php _e('Automatically add paragraphs.'); ?></label></p>
```

Some of This lines must be changed:

```
            $comment = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-comment',true);
        if ($comment == '' && $options['values']['fs_default_comment_to_excerpt'])
            $comment = $fspost->post_excerpt;
        $buttoncomment = get_post_meta($fspost->ID,'fs-button-comment',true);
        $link='';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtitles aren't standard in wordpress so it's hard to know where to find yours.

This code needs to be placed in the `frontpageSlideShow` function.

Below where it says `//format informations` add:

`$subtitle = //wherever your post subtitles can be found, probably in a custom //meta`

Then, you need to add your subtitle to the `$fscontent` variable. It is difficult to know how the plugin handles certain data, but you need to either append it on to the end of `$fscontent` or add it into the `$fsentries` array which goes into `$fscontent`.

Hopefully this gets you on the right track.